# Разница дат из строки JS

Tags: javascript, дата, input

Тут я попытался изобразить следующее:

1. В первом поле должна подставляться настоящая дата в дд.мм.гггг формате, во второе поле дата на 3 дн больше.
2. Нужно каким-то образом вычислять разницу в днях между двумя полями, чтобы потом через JS менять стили таблицы в зависимости от количества дней.

```js
//взятие настоящей даты
var d = new Date();
var day = d.getDate();
if (day < 10) {
  day = '0' + day;
} //добавление нуля перед цифрами до 10
var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
} //добавление нуля перед цифрами до 10
var year = d.getFullYear();
var feedCar = document.getElementById('my_lease_from');
feedCar.value = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

//добавление даты возвращения через 3 дня
var d2 = new Date();
var day2 = d2.getDate() + 3;
if (day2 < 10) {
  day2 = '0' + day2;
} //добавление нуля перед цифрами до 10
var month2 = d2.getMonth() + 1;
if (month2 < 10) {
  month2 = '0' + month2;
} //добавление нуля перед цифрами до 10
var year2 = d2.getFullYear();
var returnCar = document.getElementById('my_lease_before');
returnCar.value = day2 + "-" + month2 + "-" + year2;



//выделение кружком текущего тарифа по дням
var textFeed = document.getElementById('my_lease_from').value;
var dateFeed = Date.parse(textFeed);
//var dateFeed = new Date(textFeed.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, '$2/$3/$1'));
var textReturn = returnCar.value = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

alert(dateFeed);
alert(dateRerurn);
```

```html
<label>
 <span>Аренда до :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_before" id="my_lease_before">
</label>
<label>
 <span>Аренда от :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_from" id="my_lease_from">
</label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простенький пример, как ето можно сделать :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var dTo = document.querySelector('#my_lease_before');
  var dFrom = document.querySelector('#my_lease_from');

  // получаем сегодняшнюю дату
  var dNow = new Date();
  // создаем переменную для даты на 3 дня вперед
  var dThen = new Date();
  // добавляем 3 дня
  dThen.setDate(dThen.getDate() + 3);

  // записываем значения в инпуты
  dTo.value = formatDate(dNow);
  dFrom.value = formatDate(dThen);

  // дата - дата = число (милдисикунды)
  // поетому с помощью деления выщитываем количество дней
  // так как в функции parseDate время поставили по нулям, кол-во дней всегда будет целое
  // ето сделано с ращетом на то что время не играет роли
  var dd = (dThen - dNow) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
  console.log(dd);
});

function formatDate(date) {
  // для добавления нулей вначале юзаем функцию padStart
  // она работает со строками, поетому приводим числа к строке
  return [
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join('.');
  // join соеденяет елементы масива в строку через указаный разделитель
};

function parseDate(date) {
  var tmp = date.split('.');
  return new Date(tmp[2], tmp[1], tmp[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
};
```

```html
<label>
 <span>Аренда до :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_before" id="my_lease_before">
</label>
<label>
 <span>Аренда от :</span> 
 <input type="data" name="my_lease_from" id="my_lease_from">
</label>
```

Чутка "поправил" ваш код с фидла :

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var dFrom = document.querySelector('#my_lease_before');
  var dTo = document.querySelector('#my_lease_from');
  document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // получаем сегодняшнюю дату
    var dNow = new Date();
    // создаем переменную для даты на 3 дня вперед
    var dThen = new Date();
    // добавляем 3 дня
    dThen.setDate(dThen.getDate() + 3);

    // записываем значения в инпуты
    dTo.value = formatDate(dNow);
    dFrom.value = formatDate(dThen);

    // дата - дата = число (милдисикунды)
    // поетому с помощью деления выщитываем количество дней
    // так как в функции parseDate время поставили по нулям, кол-во дней всегда будет целое
    // ето сделано с ращетом на то что время не играет роли
    var dd = (dThen - dNow) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    console.log(dd);
    //alert(dd);
    if (dd <= 1) {
      var s1 = document.querySelector('.space-1');
      s1.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s1.style.background = 'red';
      s1.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s1.style.color = 'white';
      s1.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    } else if (dd > 1 && dd <= 2) {
      var s2 = document.querySelector('.space-2');
      s2.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s2.style.background = 'red';
      s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s2.style.color = 'white';
      s2.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    } else if (dd > 2 && dd <= 6) {
      var s3 = document.querySelector('.space-3');
      s3.style.borderRadius = '50%';
      s3.style.background = 'red';
      s3.style.display = 'inline-block';
      s3.style.color = 'white';
      s3.style.padding = '5px 2px';
    }
  });
});

function formatDate(date) {
  // для добавления нулей вначале юзаем функцию padStart
  // она работает со строками, поетому приводим числа к строке
  return [
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join('.');
  // join соеденяет елементы масива в строку через указаный разделитель
};

function parseDate(date) {
  var tmp = date.split('.');
  return new Date(tmp[2], tmp[1], tmp[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);

};
```

```css
.space-1,
.space-2,
.space-3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">magic</button>
<br/>

<label>
  <span>Аренда до :</span>
  <input type="data" name="my_lease_before" id="my_lease_before">
</label>
<label>
  <span>Аренда от :</span>
  <input type="data" name="my_lease_from" id="my_lease_from">
</label>
<div class="space-1"></div>
<div class="space-2"></div>
<div class="space-3"></div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yudkinWebDev/xrbp3w3y/

Comment: Вроде он, но объясните пожалуйста, за что отвечает последняя функция? Я попробовал стилизовать элемент по классу(все задано верно), но в этом случае ваш скрипт перестает функционировать.

Comment: ну так у вас в коде нету елементов с классами `space` ну и сам код вызывается 1н раз при загрузке страницы, повесьте его чтоли на изменеие значения инпутов... + куча синтакических ошибок в написаном вами коде, откройте консоль и запустите...

Comment: Да. ошибки и их много, пока не понимаю, как их исправлять. Спасибо за оперативные ответы. Я тут подумаю, как добавлять значение уже при вхоже и при изменении дат. Направьте, пожалуйста, куда думать, чтобы код постоянно не выдавал 3 дня , даже при изменении дат и почему не срабатывает style для всех классов, а только для первого. Спасибо

Comment: @ВладЮдкин погуглите про `change` событие для инпутов, а в данном примере разница 3 дня, поетому, исходя из условия `dd > 2 && dd <= 6` стили применяются только к елементу с классом `space-3`

Comment: Погулял по интернетам, с change все понятно, но до него пока не дошло. Код не хочет выделять все .space-n. querySelectorAll не срабатывает. Не написал бы сюда, если бы все ссылки не были уже фиолетовые.

Comment: сформулируйте новый вопрос с примером и задайте его